# How can we redirect 'RobotTempDir' folder to save at different location on windows 10?

Tags: robotframework, python-3.6, eclipse-oxygen

I am working with Robot Framework using RED editor on Eclipse IDE. When i ran a Robot test case an error as shown in the screenshot has occurred [image: Unable to Launch Robot]

Upon tracing back my actions, I have noticed that **RobotTempDir...** got deleted from **Temp** folder. I restored that folder and ran the test case. Then it executed successfully.

In future there are chances that while cleaning temp folder contents, **RobotTempDir...** may get deleted unknowingly. Is there a way to redirect this **RobotTempDir...** contents to save in a different location?

I looked into the **C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\robot** path and didn't find any files where i can change/update Robot temp folder details.

Answer (score 1):

The `TestRunnerAgent.py` is not part of the Robot Framework application but instead comes with the `RED` plugin. It is part of their Robot Run functionality which allows it to retrieve information from Robot Framework while it is running.

This information is then displayed in the `Eclipse Message Log panel` or used when using the RED debugger functionality.

In my view this file is generated every time Eclipse is started and I think the only time this error would occur is when that file/folder is deleted while Eclipse is running. Restarting Eclipse should fix this.

Comment: It worked, i restarted my eclipse and ran my test cases. I dint face any blockers now. **https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/src/RobotFrameworkCore/org.robotframework.ide.core-functions/src/main/java/org/rf/ide/core/executor/RobotRuntimeEnvironment.java** from this link i understood that if there's no Temp directory while we run test cases, RED will create it.

Answer (score 0):

**TestRunnerAgent.py** is custom listener which is attached to Robot process to report back to RED what is happening during test execution. For normal test runs,this is Execution View information,also Message Log stuff printed there. For Debug run, TestRunnerAgent.py allows to control execution process (breakpoint stop,stepping) and changing internals of Robot (state of variables).

It is embedded in RED package,and as you said, it is temporary placed in Temp dir for execution. If you would like to check source,either check jar file: **org.robotframework.ide.core-functions-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** or on GitHub: https://github.com/nokia/RED/tree/master/src/RobotFrameworkCore/org.robotframework.ide.core-functions/src/main/python/scripts

**Back to your issue:**

RED starts Robot execution with following command:

```
<selected python interpreter> -m robot.run --listener <path to TestRunnerAgent.py> <details what to run and other miscs>
```

There is no indication of error such error in TestRunnerAgent.py although there is in RobotLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java which tries to start Robot using interpreter in current Project configuration. I assume that there is something wrong in your env setup (either in RED or in OS)

I would suggest to check following:

- check if you selected proper python interpreter with installed Robot (from Windows->Preferences-> RobotFramework ->Interpreters
- check if your project looks similar as here: http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/quick_start.html
- you can try to use custom script to catch robot execution command and remove --listener part to validate if this is the culprit: http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/launching/local_launch_scripting.html
- there should be command in Console View - try to run it by yourself

Comment: Python interpreter is properly set in my eclipse environment. And verified your other suggestion too, though the last option was not clear to me. This link has all the details about RobotTempDir **https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/src/RobotFrameworkCore/org.robotframework.ide.core-functions/src/main/java/org/rf/ide/core/executor/RobotRuntimeEnvironment.java**